List of Sandboxes
New users can fall afoul of not knowing how to use the tools available to create their posts, they can also need a bit of a hand to structure their ideas or ensure their question is easily understandable and on-topic.
Sandboxes provide the opportunity for users to get the guidance they need to learn the basics of formatting or to polish their question 'till it's ready for posting on the relevant main site.
If you see something missing or a broken link, please edit/add-to the appropriate wiki.
There are three lists, each in its own Community Wiki:

Formatting Sandboxes
Questions and Answers Sandboxes
Chat Sandboxes
Discussion Sandboxes

Return to FAQ index

Formatting Sandboxes



Site
Sandbox Question




Arqade
Formatting sandbox


Chemistry
Formatting Sandbox III: please test stuff here


Chess
Replayer Sandbox


English Language Learners
Formatting Sandbox – Please test stuff here


Mathematics
TeX Formatting Sandbox


Mathematics Meta
MathJax Formatting Sandbox


Meta
Formatting Sandbox


Movies & TV
Formatting Sandbox


Music Practice & Theory
jTab and ABCjs Formatting Sandbox


Physics
This is a sandbox


Puzzling
The MathJax sandbox


Stack Overflow
Stack Snippets Sandbox


Stack Overflow em Português
Sandbox (ou "chiqueirinho" de formatação)


TeX - LaTeX
Formatting Sand-Box




Question and Answer Sandboxes



Site
Sandbox Question




Code Golf & Coding Challenges
Sandbox for Proposed Challenges


Computer Science Educators
The Question Sandbox


Mathematics
Sandbox for drafts of long complex posts


Puzzling
The Riddle Sandbox


Worldbuilding
Sandbox for proposed questions




Chat



Room (on chat server)




Sandbox (on chat.stackexchange.com)


Sandbox (on chat.stackoverflow.com)


Sandbox / Trash Bin (on chat.meta.stackexchange.com)




Stack Overflow Discussions



Post




 Discussion Sandbox 




Change of mind @cocomac ?

@W.O. Not sure what you mean - the one I originally had linked was deleted (hence me removing this), but a mod made a new one, so it seemed reasonable to undelete it and update the link.

Oh, I thought that was all you, my mistake. @cocomac
